# Ubuntu Touch calendar app: events imported from Google displayed on 2 days

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, calendar

I have installed Ubuntu core app calender on my BQ Aquaris E5 HD. It is working well and I have been able to sync with my google online calendar. However, I have noticed that for next month, it is showing dots for the right days (with events) and the next day has a dot too, even though there are no events for the following days. I have also checked this on the online google calendar and there is nothing on the day. I have a friends birthday on the 16th (with dot) and on the 17th there is a dot, but when I click on it, there is nothing listed.

I have looked on the net and cannot see anything for this. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: There are already some bug reports in launchpad, this is your issue: http://pad.lv/1438150, which is marked as a duplicate of http://pad.lv/1437305. Looks like these are going to be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I look forward to the fix coming soon and resolving the issue

Comment: This is still an issue and as yet there has been no update to address this. I have added comments to the defect for an update and an eta.

Comment: Status of this related bug http://pad.lv/1437305 is "fix committed". Hope this will resolve your issue too.

Comment: Thank you for the update pomsky. I look forward to the update, hopefully it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just performed an update of this calendar app with the latest update sent out today and this appears to of resolved the issue of the double dots. I have performed a sync and the dots have not returned. I can only take it that this issue has been resolved, thanks to the hard work of the app development team and pomsky for their updates. Cheers guys.